# Yii2 create a new user accounting using a restful api and facebook login

Tags: rest, yii2, ionic-framework, facebook-login

I would like to use a rest api to register new users.  The catch is that I would like to use Facebook SDK / API to do so.  My frontend app is Angual.js / Ionic.  Any suggestions?

Comment: have you got the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST is no magic in this case. Create just like you could if it was not rest. How I would it would be:

1. Log the user in using Yii2 [AuthClient](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-authclient-index.html)
2. After Success, present user a form to fill information that aren't
   provided with Facebook, if any else just jump to (3)
3. With information from FB and (2), Post to your
   UserController/actionCreate or whatever action you use for
   registering users